# How to delete rows from a DF until an empty row is found (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have built up a dictionary of dataframes containing similar data imported from many excel sheets. However, the data are a bit messy and for each DF I have a header of data I need to remove (like metadata). The problem is that this header of useless data is not always the same in terms of length so I cannot use always the same number of rows to drop while looping through these DFs.

The only common thing across all the DFs is that between this messy data and the data I need(tabular data) there is an empty excel row.
So my idea was to loop through all the DFs in this dictionary and ask starting from the first row to drop all of them until and empty row is met. Once you meet the empty row I still cancel this and then I exist the loop. I hope it is clear. Any help would be more than appreciated. BR Luigi

Comment: Do you have any example code? Please consider to check [example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, empty values are represented with `np.nan`. For a single dataframe, you can use `pd.isnull` with `all(axis=1)` to find a whole empty row. Then, you can use `idxmax` to get the first row where that is true (if you have more than 1 empty row, you'll want the first one, right?), and then `loc` with a `:` to get the "rest". Like so,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cola': [100, 99, 98, np.nan, 96, np.nan],
    'colb': [1, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5, np.nan]
})

print(df)

    cola  colb
0  100.0   1.0
1   99.0   NaN
2   98.0   3.0
3    NaN   NaN <- This is the row we want
4   96.0   5.0
5    NaN   NaN <- Not thie one

rest = df.iloc[pd.isnull(df).all(axis=1).idxmax() + 1:, :]
print(rest)

   cola  colb
4  96.0   5.0
5   NaN   NaN
```

In terms of doing it to mutiple dataframes in a dictionary, you can simply iterate over them and repeat the previous method.

```
# Sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'cola': [100, 99, 98, np.nan, 96, np.nan],
    'colb': [1, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5, np.nan]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'cola': [100, 99, 98, np.nan, 96, np.nan],
    'colb': [1, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5, np.nan]
})
dct = {'first': df1, 'second': df2}

# Solution
out_dict = {}
for key, frame in dct.items():
    new_frame = frame.iloc[pd.isnull(frame).all(axis=1).idxmax() + 1:, :].reset_index(drop=True)
    out_dict[key] = new_frame
```

`out_dict` now contains your desired dataframes.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, in the end I used df.loc['Date':][:] which helped me selecting everything after the date column (this columns is placed after the empty row) all the rest was deleted ;)